# ReactJS: Unable to parse through a 2d array outside async function

Tags: arrays, reactjs, mapping, solidity

Trying to setState of an array in an async function, and accessing it inside the async function works fine. But when I try to access it outside the async function it only parses through the first layer meaning bookDetails[0], while parsing for bookDetails[0][0] gives an error as "cannot-read-property-0-of-undefined"

```
getAll = async () => {
    const { contract } = this.state;
    const response = await contract.methods.getBooks().call();
    this.setState({ bookDetails: response});
    console.log("books: ",this.state.bookDetails[0][0]);

  };


//OUTPUT=> books:  nanme

//console.log outside the async function gives error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

notice that setState is not sync itself, you have to check the updated state in its callback:

```
getAll = async () => {
    const { contract } = this.state;
    const response = await contract.methods.getBooks().call();
    this.setState({ bookDetails: response}, () => console.log("books: ",this.state.bookDetails[0][0]);
);};
```

Other than that, the snippet is not enough to verify why outsile async function you can't log correctly. Please provide a more complete snippet.